# É possível trocar o tema ou cores do Workbench?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql, temas

Gostaria de deixar o fundo preto para cansar menos a visão. 
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um tema com essa implementação á uma questão de baixo nível da ferramenta, ou seja, a equipe de desenvolvimento que deveria implementar esse tipo de recurso.
Já existem diversas pessoas fazendo esse tio de solicitação, e você pode ser mais enviando uma requisição do recurso para: https://bugs.mysql.com/

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Farei isso, obrigado!